# Linq to SQL GetTable

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to retrieve whole table from database into my Data Grid View. I have find [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C) but in my Windows Form project doesn't exist `var q = from a in emp.GetTable<Employee>() select a;` 
Here I have an error

> Error 1   'EmployeeList.EmployeeEntities1' does not contain a definition for 'GetTable' and no extension method 'GetTable' accepting a first argument of type 'EmployeeList.EmployeeEntities1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I fix it?

I have already added `using System.Data.Linq;` but nothing has changed..

Is there any other way to retrieve whole table into my Data Grid View? Or how can I improve it

Comment: Hard to tell without more context on your code and the Data Context classes you're using, but it looks like you;re using EntityFramework and not Liq-2-sql. If not, you should call GetTable on your Context class, not on your Entity class or collection...

Comment: @jessehouwing yes, I'm using EntityFramework. I'm new there so can i say me where can i find my context class? I have only created connection and using my Entity class I'm writing values in my database. Now I want to retrieve them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the error emp should inherit from DataContext in the class definition.  DataContext has the GetTable Method.

Here is a link that should help you out.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399375(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// DataContext takes a connection string. 
DataContext db = new DataContext(@"c:\Northwnd.mdf");

// Get a typed table to run queries.
Table<Customer> Customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();

// Query for customers from London. 
var query =
    from cust in Customers
    where cust.City == "London" 
    select cust;

foreach (var cust in query)
    Console.WriteLine("id = {0}, City = {1}", cust.CustomerID, cust.City);
```

A model using a class that inherits from DataContext

```
public partial class Northwind : DataContext
{
    public Table<Customer> Customers;
    public Table<Order> Orders;
    public Northwind(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}
```

Then in your Controller.

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\Northwnd.mdf");
var query =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London" 
    select cust;
foreach (var cust in query)
    Console.WriteLine("id = {0}, City = {1}", cust.CustomerID,
        cust.City);
```